# Unable to install miam-player

Tags: dependencies

I added the following repository

```
ppa:noobslab/apps
```

Then I updated

Then I tried to install miam-player:

```
aptitude install miam-player
```

it gives me the following output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

miam-player : Depends: libqtav (>= 1.9.0~) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package.
```

But in noobslab page they say that for ubuntu 16.04 this is sufficient and nothing else is needed

Answer (score 0):

After some search in google I found that miam-player is uptill now supported only upto ubuntu 15.10 and is unsupported in Ubuntu 16.04.

The following article helped me to get to this conclusion:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/02/miam-player-open-source-qt5-music-player/

Bad Luck. I have to wait for some time now.

Answer (score -1):

You should also install this ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wbsecg1/qtav
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libqtav
```

Regards,

Comment: Apparently Ubuntu 16.04 refuses to accept that repository

Comment: Output                                                                                                                                   W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wbsecg1/qtav/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wbsecg1/qtav/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages: 404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/wbsecg1/qtav/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-i386/Packages: 404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.